# How to compare the result of jQuery get to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a .txt file hosted online with just "0.0.3" on it, (without the quotes). I am trying to compare it with a string value to check if the hard coded version is the same as the version on the .txt file.

My code:

```
$.get("http://example.com/version.txt", function(res) {
      if (res === "0.0.3") {
          console.log("works!");
      } else {
          console.log("doesnt work");
      }
});
```

This returns "doesnt work" every time. Thanks!

Comment: What output console.log(res) in the top of get callback? Also you can specify the datatType of the response https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Try removing whitespace from the returned value before comparing it: `if (res.trim() === "0.0.3") {`

Comment: If it *"doesnt work"* every time, the two strings clearly aren't the same, and we can't really help you without knowing what the other string is, and why it's not the same ?

Comment: Showing what `console.log(res)` is would have been a big help and even better would be to add additional outside characters so you can see whitespace like  `console.log('-' + res +'-')`

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

So, you may try (I assume your file is text file):

```
$.get("http://example.com/version.txt", function(res) {
    if (res.trim() === "0.0.3") {
        console.log("works!");
    } else {
        console.log("doesnt work");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is likely the solution because files often end with a newline character.

Answer (score -2):

The issue was when I was comparing them, they were different data types.

Here is how I fixed it.

```
var newVersion = "";
$.get("http://example.com/version.txt", function(res) {
    newVersion = res;
    if (newVersion === "0.0.3") {
        console.log("works!");
    } else {
        console.log("doesnt work");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the one you posted in the question? It doesn't in any way convert `res` to a string.

Comment: This is literally doing nothing other than adding another reference to the object

Comment: var newVersion = "" does not establish a permanent "type" for this variable that would cause casting when you do newVersion = res

Comment: Not at all likely it isn't already string...but for sure thing just set `dataType` argument ... change closing `});` of `$.get` to `}, 'text');`